# 'Vagrant ssh' uses old deleted box

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox

I have one box now, having deleted a previous box.  However when I do 'vagrant ssh' it seems to go that old box. How do use the new one.

current box

```
 ==> default: Checking for updates to 'fsilva/ubuntu_php5.3'
default: Latest installed version: 1.1
default: Version constraints: 
default: Provider: virtualbox
 ==> default: Box 'fsilva/ubuntu_php5.3' (v1.1) is running the latest version.
```

When I run 'vagrant ssh' shows old version 'lucid64'

```
   Linux lucid64 2.6.32-38-server #83-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jan 4 11:26:59 UTC               

  Welcome to your Vagrant-built virtual machine.
  last login: Sat Feb  4 14:49:14 2017 from 10.0.2.2
  vagrant@lucid64:~$
```

I've edited the 'Vagrantfile' line to

```
  config.vm.box = 'fsilva/ubuntu_php5.3'
```

Comment: Destroy your old instance first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The box is only used when the VM is created (actually vagrant clones the box to create the VM). After your VM is created the box is useless, vagrant will only operates this VM instance and does not mind if the box exists or not. (you can make a test, once the VM is created you can replace `config.vm.box = "thisdoesnotexistbox"` in your vagrantfile and it work just fine)

If you want your VM to be built on top of the most recent boxes, you need to destroy and recreates the VM (`vagrant destroy && vagrant up`)